# order by foreign key mysql same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have one table (table order), with foreign key indexed to the same table, every order has many other orders :

```
 order             
 ---------- 
 id_order
 state
 id_source
```

id_source is a foreign key refrenced to id_order in the same table

I want to select all rows ordered by state of order and their orders.

I tried this code but it did'nt  give me what I want.

```
  select * from order o left join order o2 ON(o.id_order = o2.id_source)
  order by o.state , o2.state asc ;
```

For example  :

```
 id_order  |   state  |   id_source 
 -----------------------------------
     1     |     1    |     null
 -----------------------------------
     2     |     2    |     null  
 -----------------------------------
     3     |     3    |     null
 -----------------------------------
     4     |     1     |    3
```

The result that I want

```
   id_order  |   state  |   id_source 
 -----------------------------------
     1       |     1    |     null
 -----------------------------------
     3       |     3    |     null
 -----------------------------------
     4       |     1    |    3
 -----------------------------------
     2       |     2    |     null
```

Comment: provide your expected output

Comment: Please show sample data for both tables, and the output you expect.

Comment: please check my updated question.Thank you

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but the result you want doesn't seem to have any order

Comment: I want to order the main orders which their id_source is null by state and if they had orders the order change with state of their children

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding you correctly then you want to use a conditional statement on the order by, which is possible with the following:

```
select * 
from order o 
left join order o2 ON(o.id_order = o2.id_source)
order by if(id_source is null, o.state, o2.state) asc;
```